# How to store data only if data is changed from previous value?

Tags: c#, winforms

I coded program that receives value every 3 seconds but I want to only store it if the value is not same as before. For example, if first value was 10001 and second value is 10002 and so on and change interval for these values are not consistent. So it records 10001 and keep reading values after that but only store the value when reading value becomes 10002.

How do I accomplish this?

Comment: Where do you store the values? If it's a database, then make your query to check if the value exists and if so don't insert, else insert a new record.

Comment: `if (currentValue != newValue) currentValue = newValue;`?

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are only saving the value if there is a change. You would also need to store the value if your array (or whatever data source you use) is empty.

It may help if you post some code, and give more insight into how you are storing the value.

Comment: While I agree with the idea (especially the last line), isn't this more of a comment to assist with editing the question than it is an _answer_?

Comment: I contemplated this while writing a comment, and I did feel I understood the OP's question. So yes, I did feel my first part was an answer, and the second part was a comment.